How to improve the capacitor dropper circuit?
I am new to electronics and I am trying to build an iontophoresis device which should give a output of current in mA.
This is the first part , i.e, the rectifier. I am sure it is not efficient and must be having some serious issues.
Please guide me by improving the circuit.
Circuit:


Are you aware of the inherent dangers of this circuit? Is the output user-accessible in any way?

What's the input voltage? Without a load, the second circuit should be delivering 1.414 times the input rms, ie 340 V for a 240 V AC input. The second circuit is only safe for use with sealed and non-accessible devices like light bulbs, as there's no isolation from the mains.

"I am sure it is not efficient and must be having some serious issues. "  Really?  First, without knowing the required output current there is no way to tell what the efficiency is.  Second, how/why are you "sure"?  Just because a circuit has been used successfully by the billions in the last century is no reason to dismiss it out of hand.  Third, patient-contact electronics are extremely dangerous.  It is the 2nd circuit that has serious issues.  It would be banned in every country on earth.

I'm curious how you are "new to electronics" but have been assigned to work on an iontophoresis device. That's like being new to nuclear physics, but you want to design a fusion reactor. In other words, this is not where you start and someone's going to get hurt.

How to improve the capacitor dropper circuit? For your application, you do this by using a transformer.

I had to look up "iontophoresis", apparently it means applying a weak current through skin.
If you build it with a capacitive dropper, it is not isolated from mains, and it will be a deadly electrocution device.
How to improve it obviously means, do not use a capacitive dropper at all, but anything that uses medical grade isolation.
